# how to add map layer overlays in openlayers?

Tags: maps, gis, openlayers, mapserver

i have 3 shapefile ready in a map file, and rendering it on mapserver. what i need is to and these layer overlay one over the other.how can i do this

Comment: Can you elaborate:  How are you rendering the shapefile? Is Mapserver acting as a WMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [this](http://maps.tikiwiki.org/Tutorial:+Mapfile+Editing&structure=Tikiwiki+mapserver#Layers) help?

for your question in the comment,

[General openlayers examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) You'll also find [Geoext](http://www.geoext.org/) useful.

In the examples, you can see the different ways to add a layer to open layers

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i need to know how to accomplish layer overlays using openlayer library

Answer (score 0):

When you define a map in openlayers you should define one or more BaseLayer(but just one of them is displayed at a time). Upon these layer you could load as many overlay as you prefer.

Have a look [here](http://trac.openlayers.org/wiki/Overlay) for the definition of overlay in OpenLayers.

[This](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/layer-opacity.html) is an example of overlay with OpenLayers.

Anyway you could find a lot of samples just googling..